# How can I update this legacy SQL code to something compatible with SQL2012?

Tags: sql-server, outer-join, legacy-code

I've been looking at some very outdated SQL code lately to investigate how feasible it would be to update to a SQL 2012-2014 compatible structure. I'm a bit stumped with what to do with this chunk.

Obviously, this is very dated code and still contains *= in place of a Left Outer Join. I hope someone would have some advice on how to go about updating this code as I seem to get various syntax errors with the "IF" statements when I try to update the table joins.

```
If @Type = 'Edit'  
Begin
    If @Area = 'Box'
        Declare CursorInv Cursor For 
            Select Retention_Code, 
                Company_Id, 
                Department_Id, 
                Group_Id, 
                Section_Id, 
                Locator_Id, 
                Location_Current, 
                Location_Home, 
                Box_User_Defined1.Udf_Code User_Defined1, 
                Box_User_Defined2.Udf_Code User_Defined2, 
                Box_User_Defined3.Udf_Code User_Defined3
            From Box, Box_User_Defined1, Box_User_Defined2,    Box_User_Defined3
            Where Box_Number = @KeyValue And 
                Box.User_Defined1 *= Box_User_Defined1.ID And 
                Box.User_Defined2 *= Box_User_Defined2.ID And 
                Box.User_Defined3 *= Box_User_Defined3.ID
    If @Area = 'Folder'
        Declare CursorInv Cursor For 
            Select Retention_Code, 
                Company_Id, 
                Department_Id, 
                Group_Id, 
                Section_Id, 
                Locator_Id, 
                Location_Current, 
                Location_Home,  
                Folder_User_Defined1.Udf_Code User_Defined1, 
                Folder_User_Defined2.Udf_Code User_Defined2, 
                Folder_User_Defined3.Udf_Code User_Defined3
            From Folder, Folder_User_Defined1, Folder_User_Defined2, Folder_User_Defined3
            Where Folder_Number = @KeyValue And 
                Folder.User_Defined1 *= Folder_User_Defined1.ID And 
                Folder.User_Defined2 *= Folder_User_Defined2.ID And 
                Folder.User_Defined3 *= Folder_User_Defined3.ID
    If @Area = 'Document'
        Declare CursorInv Cursor For 
            Select Retention_Code, 
                Company_Id, 
                Department_Id, 
                Group_Id, 
                Section_Id, 
                Locator_Id, 
                Location_Current, 
                Location_Home, 
                Document_User_Defined1.Udf_Code User_Defined1, 
                Document_User_Defined2.Udf_Code User_Defined2, 
                Document_User_Defined3.Udf_Code User_Defined3
            From Document, Document_User_Defined1, Document_User_Defined2, Document_User_Defined3
            Where Document_Number = @KeyValue And 
                Document.User_Defined1 *= Document_User_Defined1.ID And 
                Document.User_Defined2 *= Document_User_Defined2.ID And 
                Document.User_Defined3 *= Document_User_Defined3.ID

    Open CursorInv
    Fetch Next From CursorInv Into  @Retention_Code_Old, 
                    @Company_Id_Old, 
                    @Department_Id_Old, 
                    @Group_Id_Old, 
                    @Section_Id_Old, 
                    @Locator_Id_Old, 
                    @Location_Current_Old, 
                    @Location_Home_Old,
                    @User_Defined1_Old, 
                    @User_Defined2_Old, 
                    @User_Defined3_Old
    Close CursorInv
    Deallocate CursorInv
End
```

Comment: Please provide details of actual errors

Comment: replace the joins as you have already said. There is no need for the cursors you can assign the variables using select. If the queries return more than one row you will need to use top.

Comment: One you get the values into these variables what do you do next ?? this is not all of the code? or is it ?? The whole things needs to be re-written.

Comment: have you tried using the while loop in sql? just create a table variable with the desired columns and based on your condition add values in it using the while loop. you wont be needing cursors. cursors tend to slow down your query. while loop is better.